# Ошибка при добавлении в проект базы данных

Tags: c#, sql-server

При попытке добавить базу данных MS SQL Server Express в проект появляется ошибка 
Только что поставил новую версию SQL. До этого была эта ошибка, и она не решилась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ConnectionStrings:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Assortiment"
       connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
         AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Assortiment.mdf;User Instance=true"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Как решить эту проблему?

```
<System>
  <Provider Name="SQLLocalDB 11.0" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="35269">520</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-12-04T06:35:05.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>81750</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>Gas_2</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
```

Comment: Причин может быть несколько. Ты сделал конyект к этой базе не посредственно в VS? Ты наверное поставил `SQL Server 2014`. Посмотри, что говорят об этом [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno)

Comment: @adamshakhabov, я даже коннект не могу сделать, потому что БД не создается. Получается создать Локальную БД SQL Server Compact 4.0, а обычную БД SQL Server не выходит, возникает эта ошибка.

Comment: у Вас используется EF?

Comment: @Bald56rus что за EF?

Comment: @max619 вы прочитали сообщение об ошибке? проверили дополнительные сведения об ошибке в журнале Windows - том, который Event Log?

Comment: @PashaPash http://i.imgur.com/bsRwJcK.png

Comment: @max619 скриншот это отлично, а теперь откройте сам просмотр событий и найдите там конкретную ошибку.

Comment: @PashaPash добавил в вопрос

Comment: @PashaPash репаир лог http://text.fancy.kz/nwgj

Comment: @max619 причем тут repair.log? у вас ошибка с подключением или с установкой? если с установкой - то решите ее - какой смысл создавать пост с ошибкой подклчюения к серверу, который у вас даже не установлен???

Comment: @max619 скачайте  с сайта MS нормальный SQL Server 2014 Express и установите. а потом уже пытайтесь к нему подключится. а 2008 выкиньте на помойку, он давным-давно не поддерживается.

Comment: @PashaPash у тс первоначальная проблема с созданием бд, а приведенный лог это уже следствие попыток *починить*

Comment: @Bald56rus да, и подробности ошибки были в Event Log. который я попросил выше. И который топикастер уже не привел, да уже и не приведет, судя по всему - потому что SQL Server сломан.

Comment: @Bald56rus я бы сказал "проблема больше не воспроизводится". теперь действительно стоит просто установить новый SQL Server.

Comment: @PashaPash проблема уже решилась: переустановкой сервера и настройкой доступа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо проверить в *SQL Server Configuration Manager* разрешения на подключение по IP или по имени, в зависимости от того как подключались раньше. Если там все хорошо — смотрим фаервол на предмет разрешения поключения к базе данных. Если там все плохо, то добавляем необходимые записи.

**Настройка доступа к экземпляру SQL**:

Необходимо запустить *SQL Server Configuration Manager* - Пуск → Все программы → Microsoft SQL Server {Ваша версия} → Средства настройки → Диспетчер конфигурации SQL сервера.

В открывшемся окне: Сетевая конфигурация SQL Server → Протоколы для {Ваша версия SQL} убедиться что **TCP/IP** в состоянии включен. Если выключен, то в свойствах протокола включаем его.

более подробно [здесь](http://ts-soft.ru/blog/install-sql-server)

**UPD:**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <remove name="AssortimentDb" />
  <add name="AssortimentDb" 
       connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Assortiment; Integrated Security=True" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: TCP/IP включен, а фаервол выключен, значит в чем-то другом проблема. Кстати говоря, в менеджере не могу выбрать версию, а в меню пуск есть SQL Server 2008 и SQL Server 2014, но в первом нету менеджера, только во втором.

Comment: @max619 у вас еще и ошибка в connectionString, вы там пытаетесь подключится к серверу и при этом указываете путь к файлу. Сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: @max619, добавил исправленный connectionString. Ну и базу неплохо бы завести до того как вы будите пытыться ее использовать. сделать это можно через менеджмент студию

Comment: Это конечно не удивительно, но это проблему не решило. Но спасибо за исправление

Comment: @max619 еще как вариант попробуйте поменять `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS` на `Data Source=localhost`, а вообще, чтобы правильно ответить на ваш вопрос необходимо больше информации, как установлен инстанс базы? какие настройки сетевые уже сделаны и тд, лучше в скриншотах

Comment: @max619, окончательно подправил `connectionString`, попробуйте

Comment: Нет, ничего не изменилось

Comment: я прочитал, что, возможно конфликтуют между собой разные версии. Попробую разобраться сейчас с этим

Comment: Если вам нетрудно подсказать, что где можно найти, то я сделаю добавлю эту информацию.

Comment: @max619 вам необходимо разобраться с настройками базы, если у вас в системе установлено более одной базы, то вам необходимо переименовать один из инстансов

Comment: Похоже я сделал только хуже, я удалил MS Sql 2008 и удалил все записи в реестре, в надежде что при переустановке они вернуться, но похоже я был неправ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32495/discussion-between-dmitry-and-max619).